# javascript is combining my label tags

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to have my javascript create a form for me. it needs to have an amount of the lines, based on the amount from an alert box, and I'm running this code in a loop.

```
    //creates 4 elements for the form
    var name = document.createElement("input");
    var text1 = document.createElement("label");
    var initiative = document.createElement("input");
    var text2 = text1 = document.createElement("label");
    //gives the input tags the type and name values
    name.setAttribute("type", "text");
    initiative.setAttribute("type", "text");
    name.setAttribute("name", "name");
    initiative.setAttribute("name", "init");
    //gives the 2 span elements text
    text1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" has "));
    text2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" for initiative."));
    text2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    //adds the elements to the form
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(name);

    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(text1);

    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(initiative);

    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(text2);
```

the code here should work, but the actual form has the elements like this

```
<input type="text" name="name>
<input type="text" name="init">
<label> has </label>
<label> for initiative </label>
```

but based on the order of the javascript, it should be

```
<input type="text" name="name>
<label> has </label>
<input type="text" name="init">
<label> for initiative </label>
```

edit: i didn't realise there text1 = text2. I accidentally put it there and didn't even realize it was there, and that was the problem

Comment: You should post what you expect the form to look like as well as what you actually get. You might also find it easier and saner to just construct the bowels of your form as a string and then simply blast it in with `innerHtml`.

Comment: The code and the result match together. What result do you expect?

Comment: the form i should get should be clearly visable from the last 4 javascript commands, but it should be input, text, input, text

Comment: im adding the input(name), then the text(text1), then another input(initiative), then another text,(text2), it should be adding them in that order, not the inputs first

Comment: Edit your question to clarify it, don't keep explaining it in comments. Question should generally contain what happens, what you expect to happen and how they differ.

Comment: @TylerSilva it is not adding in that order as `text2=text1`... run the code snippet in answer

Comment: the `text2 = text1` bit makes no sense. You already initialized `text1`. Why are you fiddling with it again?

Comment: @pvg yes thats present in OP's code in the question. Thats what I pointed out in answer.. why the downvote?

Comment: i didnt realise i had that in my code, i must have put it there without thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is combining labels because of this line present in the code

`var text2 = text1 = document.createElement("label");`

As text2 = text1, it is combining both labels.

Please remove the `text2=text1`

[Here is a fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/g0hzgq4y/)

Also I think it should be `document.createElement("INPUT")` and not `document.createElement("input")`. For some reason I was getting the error cannot setAttribute for `input`

```js
//creates 4 elements for the form
var name1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
var text1 = document.createElement("label");
var initiative = document.createElement("INPUT");
var text2 = document.createElement("label");
//gives the input tags the type and name values
name1.setAttribute("type", "text");
initiative.setAttribute("type", "text");
name1.setAttribute("name", "name");
initiative.setAttribute("name", "init");
//gives the 2 span elements text
text1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" has "));
text2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" for initiative."));
text2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
//adds the elements to the form
document.getElementById("form").appendChild(name1);

document.getElementById("form").appendChild(text1);

document.getElementById("form").appendChild(initiative);

document.getElementById("form").appendChild(text2);
```

```html
<div id="form">
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is they had a problem with this incorrect statement: `As text2 = text1, it is combining both labels.`  I see what you are trying to say, but don't think it's coming out how others are reading it

Comment: But if you run the snippet, without `text2=text1`, the elements are in order as OP has stated in comment

Comment: whoops, i didnt even realize i did text1 = text2, that makes more sense now, thx